# Practical Example: Expectation of a function with respect to a probability

Tags: conditional-expectation, machine-learning, expected-value, pattern-recognition

I have encountered the following phrasing while reading Bishop's "[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf)":

> Although for some applications the posterior distribution over unobserved variables will be of direct interest in itself, for most situations the  posterior distribution is required primarily for the purpose of **evaluating expectations**, for example in order to make predictions.

As I know from Neural Networks, you usually want the posterior for predictions. Therefore I don't understand what the use-case for evaluating expectations would be.

If you could please help me with a couple of practical examples for where one would decide to compute expectations of functions with respect to a probability or redirect me to an explanation, I would be very thankful.

Comment: The [posterior distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability) is a distribution for the parameter(s).  The [posterior predictive distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution) is then a distribution for the next observation.  If you want to make a point prediction, then the mean of the posterior predictive distribution is often a sensible choice, especially if you have a loss function based on the square of the error